# simplification of a natural log of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

hope you are all well.

I am having a bit of a mental block, I am wondering if it is possible to simplify the following expression:
$$k\cos X \cdot 4\ln(\cos X)$$
where $k$ is a constant and $X$ ranges between $0$ to $60$ degrees.

Comment: No it cannot be simplified any further.

Comment: I didn't think so - thank you for your time and also for fixing the formatting of my question.

Comment: @Daryl : Can you prove that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy No. By inspection, no logarithmic or trig "laws" can be used. I suspect this is to be Dione using those in a situation for practising algebra.

Comment: Probably in some special cases where $X$ is a rational number times $\pi$, this can be simplified.

Comment: Yes, X represents an angle in radians, so would be a rational times pi

Comment: okay, thank you for your time.  Sorry to have bothered you both.